# Updating table using merge and use defined table type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Order]
    @tblOrderProduct [ProductOrderType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
    MERGE INTO tblKmOrder AS c1
    USING @tblOrderProduct c2 ON c1.id = c2.id 

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET c1.client = c2.client
END
```

and type like this

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ProductOrderType] AS TABLE(id int, client nvarchar(max) null)
```

I am passing datatable as parameter to a stored procedure. The problem is the value are not mapping properly, I am using `c1.client = c2.client` but `c2.client` value is not getting mapped; instead id value gets mapped because I pass datatable like this

```
id | client 
 1 | somename
```

and I pass like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + parameter, dt);
```

Why does this fail?

Comment: What do you mean with "mapping"? You match the ID and you update the client field. If you want to match the cient field, write `c1.client=c2.client` instead of `c1.id=c2.id`

Comment: @Sefe  nope, I want to match id only, I mean with mapping  is that suppose id in not int and its nvarchar ans suppose i exec the sp id updates with client

Comment: Your stored procedure seems fine, try changing your c# code for adding the parameter to `cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + parameter, SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;`. Also, read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled not working

Comment: can you show your data table? it's important that it's the same structure as the table type defined in the sql server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled structure is same but the columns sequence is different

Comment: That might be the reason. make sure the columns are in the same order as the columns defined in the table type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  yes that is the reason actually, is there any other way to work around this problem, why with the sequence ?

Comment: Not that I know of. The order of columns of the sql table type must fit the order of the columns of the .Net dataTable exactly. Why isn't the column names enough? I have no idea.

Comment: I will search something Thanks guys  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns defined in the .Net DataTable must match exactly the columns defined in the user defined table type, including the order of the columns.

if, for instance, your user defined table type is defined like this:

```
CREATE TYPE udtt AS TABLE
(
    id int,
    val int
)
```

Your c# DataTable must be defined like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(int));
```

If the order of the columns is wrong, you get the columns in the stored procedure wrong. This means that if your data table would have been defined like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
```

Your stored procedure would take whatever is in the "val" column in the data table as the "id" column and vice versa.